# Using the datediff and sum when the row contains an isnull

Tags: mysql, datetime, sum

I need to do the following calculations in MySQL

```
IFNULL(c.ACTUAL_END_DATE, CURDATE()) AS ACTUAL_END_DATE
```

Currently, I have two date time fields i'd like to do the datediff and find the total number of days while compensating for the "is null" as I have done already

I would then like to sum the days

```
SELECT 
    a.PERSONNEL_ID,
    a.LAST_NAME,
    a.FIRST_NAME,
    b.NUM,
    c.ACTUAL_START_DATE,
    c.payroll_job_id,
    IFNULL(c.ACTUAL_END_DATE, CURDATE()) AS ACTUAL_END_DATE
FROM
    personnel a,
    num b,
    personnel_service c
WHERE
    a.CURRENTLY_SERVING_SHIP_ID = b.ship_id
        AND a.current_status_lookupitem = 10142
        AND a.personnel_id = c.personnel_id
        AND c.payroll_job_id IN ('1')
        AND c.SERVICE_TYPE_LOOKUPITEM = 10161 
        AND c.ACTUAL_START_DATE is not null
```

Comment: By sum you do mean the SQL function sum that adds up the value of a column for multiple rows? If so, what would you group by?

Comment: I would group by name most likely